# How do I turn setting a property on ngTable into a promise?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ngtable

I'm trying to 'promisify' the following call:

```
$scope.productsTable.params.page(page);
```

My goal is to manually jump to a certain page, then do some stuff on that page once the page is loaded.

The problem is that the `page()` method doesn't return a promise, so I have to manually create one. I'm just not sure how to do this.

Someone mentioned I can use `$q.when(params.page(n))`, but this didn't work... so perhaps I'm using it wrong?

Here is the `page()` method: https://github.com/esvit/ng-table/blob/master/ng-table.js#L148-L150

That then triggers the `$watch` (which calls `reload()` which uses ajax).

https://github.com/esvit/ng-table/blob/master/ng-table.js#L481-L492

I was thinking of trying to create my own custom `page()` method which doesnt trigger the watch, and calls reload manually (or getData). Wasn't sure how to do that.

Here was my actual table

```
$scope.productsTable.params = new ngTableParams({
  page:  1,
  count: 200
}, {
  counts: [20, 50, 200, 500, 1000, 2000],
  filterDelay: 0,
  total: 0,
  getData: function($defer, params) {
    Model.apiFullResponse.('ajax endpoint stuff')
    .then(function(response) {
      $scope.products = response.data;
      // stuff
      $defer.resolve($scope.products);
    });
  }
});
```

My ideal solution would be to end up with something like this...

```
$scope.productsTable.params.page(page).then(function() {
  // do stuff
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
 var promise = $q.when($scope.productsTable.params.page(page))
  if(promise.then)
     promise.all(function(){//do staff})
  else
   //do staff without promise
```

In your case, page method don't return any promise from source code just returs params object or factory. By using promise.all Combines multiple promises into a single promise that is resolved when all of the input promises are resolved. If there is no promise, means that you don't need waiting for promise, if exist you should waiting for resolve

Comment: Please provide an explanation of how this code answers the question. Simply saying "Try" followed by code does not help people who come to the question and answer in the future understand how the answer works.

Comment: Ok sorry, I have seen you as an expert user of angular. In your case, page method don't return any promise from source code just returs params object or factory. By using promise.all Combines multiple promises into a single promise that is resolved when all of the input promises are resolved. If there is no promise, means that you don't need waiting for promise, if exist you should waiting for resolve.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a classic forum. It exists as a repository of high quality questions and answers, and thus one should not assume a level of expertise based on the "questioner's" words (and BTW, I am not the original poster). Thus, explanations are critical in maintaining that high level of quality, not just for the OP, but for everyone who gets here from search engines, blogs, etc.. So, please edit the explanation into your answer, as comments can get deleted without warning.